# Presentational wrappers for simple components

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm an angular 2 beginner.

I currently have a custom button component like so...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-button',
    template: `
    <button md-button>{{buttonText}}</button>
    `,
})

export class MyButtonComponent {

    buttonText: string;

    constructor(){
        this.buttonText = 'abc'
    }
}
```

which I'm using in my `AppComponent` as:

```
<my-button></my-button>
```

so far so good. The button says 'abc'.

Is there any way I can specify the button text where I say `<my-button>`? I mean like

```
<my-button newText='xyz'></my-button>
```

Is there any way to configure this behavior? All the examples I've seen show the flow of variables from child to parent (so to speak) but never the other way around.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Input` to expect value from parent component. You just need to place `Input` decorator over `buttonText` property.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-button',
    template: `
    <button md-button>{{buttonText}}</button>
    `,
})
export class MyButtonComponent {

    @Input() buttonText: string;

    constructor(){
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted it. Was waiting for other answers.